# How to remove the first and last characters in AngularJS when pushing to an array?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, substring, character

When I push the new value into an array, it pushes with the [ ] brackets. I want to remove these brackets and pass it to the backend.

```
$scope.set = { values: [] };

$scope.add = function (){
$scope.set.values.push('');
```

}

Imagine a user adds values; red, blue, black

It saves an array as

0: [red,

1: blue,

2: black]

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Give more description of what you need here. I can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to push the array element inside the `values` array like this:

```
$scope.set = { values: [] };
$scope.add = function (){
  $scope.set.values.push(''); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had .values but forgot to put in the question.

Comment: This below code will help you to remove the first and last character of a string 
`var value = "somerandomtext";`
`var processedValue = value.substr(1, value.length-2);`

Comment: @sivaram636, but how can I relate this technique to an array as given above.

Comment: you can use array.map method to iterate each items and make the above logic as a function to process each item.